# Not able to ssh into server after mounting users home on other ebs volume

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-ebs

I have a server which has a low storage problem.
What i want is to mount the user `ec2-user`'s home directory that is `/home/ec2-user` to another attached storage drive which is available at `/dev/xvdk` and its partitioned as `xfs` and the partition is `/dev/xvdk1`.
So what i did is login as `bob` and rename `/home/ec2-user` to `/etc/ec-user-backup/` and then `rsync` all files to the extra attached storage in `/dev/xvdk1`. Then mount that drive at `/drive2`. So now the c2-user's home directory is present at `/drive2/ec2-user/`. Now I create a symlink in `/home/ec2-user` which points to `/drive2/ec2-user`.

I also update the `/etc/fstab` accordingly. Check with `mount -a`. `ec2-user`'s home directory has moved to new storage and is working.

The problem arises when i try to ssh in as `ec2-user`. The ssh key that was working previously has stopped working now. I have looked at the permissions on user's `.ssh` and all files under this and they seem to be alright. which is `600`. Also im able to login in with password but not the ssh key.

What am i missing?

Comment: Check the server logs.

Comment: @JennyD which logs in specific. And what should I be looking for.

Comment: If you don't know which logs then this isn't the site for your question.

Comment: @Iain what are you suggesting?

Comment: And yes I know which logs to look at but that shouldn't be the criteria for this question being valid for this site.

Comment: The logs for the service you are trying and failing to connect to. In this case, sshd. And yes, knowing which logs to look at *is* part of the criteria for a question being valid on this site. See http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on that.

Comment: @JennyD thanks for the clarification of validity. The key is being rejected. I have a snapshot of the server prior to mounting and it works with same files. But not after mounting and symlinking.

Comment: I've tried mounting the new drive on /home/ec2-user directly. No effect.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @lain is this clear enough? I have updated the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is closed.  The question is clear and makes perfect sense to me.  Today (December 2022) I ran into a similar problem with Fedora 37.  I could no longer log in with `ssh` as a non-`root` user after I manually mounted a new `/home` partition.  I could still `ssh` in as `root`.  I suspected I was hitting a security policy of some kind.  After some research, I tried disabling SELinux with `sudo setenforce 0`.  Then I could log in again.  (I am unfamiliar with SELinux, so I don't know the details of how SELinux is interacting with `sshd`.)

Answer (score 2):

The `.ssh` directory needs to have `u+x` permission set too

```
chmod u+x /home/ec2user/.ssh
```

Comment: This has no effect.